# Problem with Vue3 Vite .env during development mode

Tags: process, environment-variables, vuejs3, vite, dotenv

I have problem with acces the .env variables.
In my Vite cli project I'v added .env variables:

```
VITE_SOME_KEY = 123
```

and then in js file:

```
console.log(import.meta.env.DEV); 
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY);
```

It's working after build and serve. But during development (npm run vite) i have problem:

```
Module "process" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "process.env" in client code.
```

I check all documentation from vite enviroments but I don't understand how to use .env during development localy

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix your custom environment variables with VITE_ to make them available in your code. For example, if you want to use a variable named DEV, you need to define it as DEV in your .env file or in your system.

console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_DEV);
console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY);